# Differences in GPIO between Raspberry Pi 3 B and 3 B+

Tags: pi-3, gpio, pi-3b+

Is there any difference in the GPIO layout between Raspberry Pi 3 B and 3 B+? If yes, please provide the differences.

Comment: you could've discovered the answer after some 10 seconds of research. But you'd rather spend that time asking someone else to google it for you, then wait 4 hours for the answer to be posted?

Answer (score 5):

No, the GPIO pin layout has not changed between Pi3B and Pi3B+
Actually, it has not changed since the introduction of the Pi Model B+ in July 2014.